# Urban Airship Tags don't work

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

I am trying to use Urban Airship to filter push messages with tags but it seems it's not working.

Let's say I have the following tags:

```
1. house
2. apartment
3. etc
```

Now let's say user does something in my map and he becomes tagged with "house". Tagging is done like this:

```
Set<String> tags = UAirship.shared().getPushManager().getTags()
tags.add("house")
UAirship.shared().getPushManager().setTags(tags);
```

Now I go to Urban Airship console and do the following steps:

1. Under "Audience" I select **Segment**
2. Then I select **Tags**
3. I add the tag "apartment"
4. Send message

**Expected Result:** All devices tagged with "apartment" would receive notification and those tagged with only with "house" won't receive notification.

**Actual Result:** All users received the message.

What could be the problem here? Thanks.